# Android redrawing overlaying transparent bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing

I have a transparent bitmap (clock face) that I redraw to mimic
a chronograph, and it works perfectly( overlaying different dials) use a base 
empty faceplate PNG and draw the needles on top of it with a little trig/high school stuff

The problem: I need to loop thru this updating the values of the needles and overlaying 
several dials., it works but the border gets grainy the more I loop thru it, if I use a non-transparent base faceplate it is fine... I've been trying all kinds of things/suggestions without success, I need the transparency to work for the overlaying.

Some resizing goes on as the final `ImageView` size where it is drawn can be different than the base faceplate size, tried `createScaleBitmap`, with a Matrix no difference stayed with the basic `drawBitmap(bmp, rect1, rect2, myPaint)`

- Did use the `ARG_8888` creating my bitmaps
- have a method that returns the transparent bitmap with the needle worked out properly
- I draw this on an ImageView  with `setImageBitmapm` tried drawing on a bitmap first 
  but no difference
- try to clear the bitmap before drawing the `dials(PorterDuff.mode)`, no difference

Is there any trick or unknown way Android handles the transparent redrawing? Will setting Alpha to Zero make any difference? My Bitmap is already transparent.

Comment: without posting code, it is hard to know what the issue is. As a suggestion, why not have your images be the hands, and set up an animation interval.

Comment: I got around it...I had the faceplate as an RGB PNG I changed it to indexed, 16-bit colours is the best most Androids can do...  and I don't get the graining of the rounded border when looping no more but it lost the sharpness of  the rounded edges, not sure if there is a way around it. When I used RGB the edges came really sharp/smooth. I see people talking about touching it bit/bit aftwerards but it sounds like it may be overkill.